# How do i set an eVar value in Adobe Analytics?

Tags: adobe-analytics

I couldn't find an answer to my question anywhere so i decided to post it here.

So, we have eVar33 set up within adobe analytics, when someone submits a form on our website how do i set eVar33 equal to the email address field?

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    $("input#email").val(eVar33);
});
```

Comment: The code you posted is jQuery syntax. The code listens for form submits and on form submit, it attempts to set the value of an _input field_ .  IOW it seems your issue goes beyond setting an Adobe Analytics variable - seems like you are struggling with coding concepts in general.  Do you have a developer resource to do this for you?

Comment: At a minimum, you code should be more like `$("form").submit(function(){
    s.eVar33 = $("input#email").val();
});`  But this will only set the AA variable. There's more to it than that to send it off to Adobe collection server. But without insight into your AA setup, there's no way to give you a solid answer for what you ultimately need to do.

Comment: But ideally, you shouldn't need to be doing this stuff directly. Ideally, you should have a tag manager (like Adobe Tag Manager) on your site, and an event based rule to trigger on form submit and populate eVar33 from within the tag manager interface

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have an appmeasurement library (aka s_code) on your page. In that case, Crayon Violet is right, something like this is what you want:

```
$("form").submit(function(){ 
     s.eVar33 = $("input#email").val(); 
});
```

That will set the variable. To send it to Adobe, you need to fire either s.t() (for a page view) or, as is more likely the case for you, s.tl() (for things you want to track not associated with a page view- https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/function_tl.html and https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/link_variables.html.) 
I suspect in the end, you'd do something like this:

```
$("form").submit(function(){ 
     s.eVar33 = $("input#email").val(); 
     s.linkTrackVars="eVar33"
     s.tl(this,"o","form submitted")
});
```